# Thunderbird can not get messages

Tags: thunderbird, ubuntu-mate

TB times out when it tries to download messages.

Here are my settings.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zgg9oovwv3uolo3/smtp.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xxivoddm1zhg91/Incoming_Server.png?dl=0

Can someone see something wrong with my settings?

ufw status
Status: inactive

2/24/19 UPDATE

This is supposed to show open ports.

If so, none of the ports I need are open. Namely 993,465,587

```
?sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      841/rpcbind         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      844/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      853/cupsd           
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      841/rpcbind         
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      853/cupsd
```

Comment: Have you checked your firewall settings? UFW and iptables. Also you've left your email in one picture, you may want to edit that.

Comment: sudo iptables -L -n
 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination  Do not know what UFW is.

Answer (score 2):

**You've defined your incoming mail server as IMAP, but given it a server address of pop.mail.yahoo.com, and an incorrect port #.**

---

See the following two links for possible issues getting your mail.

https://help.yahoo.com/kb/fix-pop-imap-client-sending-receiving-issues-sln3792.html

https://help.yahoo.com/kb/generate-third-party-passwords-sln15241.html

See below for IMAP and POP server settings.

---

**How POP and IMAP differ**

IMAP (Internet Message Access Protocol) is a newer protocol that allows you to remotely access and manage your email. What you do in the app affects email on the email server.

```
2-way sync - Emails stay on the server and are accessed remotely.
Full access - Access every email from every folder using the app.
Record of sent email - Email you send using the app is saved on the server.
Manage mailbox once - Emails deleted or moved in the app are deleted or moved on the server.
```

POP (Post Office Protocol) is an older protocol that copies emails from the email server to the app. Actions performed in the app don't affect email on the email server.

```
1-way sync - Only downloads email from the server.
Limited access - Only download emails from the Inbox.
No record of sent email - Emails sent from the app are not saved on the server.
Manage Inboxes independently - Deleting or moving email in the app isn't reflected on the server.
Keep email on server options - Different settings allow you to leave a copy of your email on the server, or delete it when it's downloaded.
```

---

**Use these settings for IMAP...**

Incoming Mail (IMAP) Server

```
Server - imap.mail.yahoo.com
Port - 993
Requires SSL - Yes
```

Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server

```
Server - smtp.mail.yahoo.com
Port - 465 or 587
Requires SSL - Yes
Requires authentication - Yes
```

Your login info

```
Email address - Your full email address (name@domain.com)
Password - Your account's password
Requires authentication - Yes
```

Source: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN4075.html

**Update #1:**

**Use these settings for POP...**

POP (Post Office Protocol) is 1 way to get Yahoo Mail in a desktop or mobile app. POP downloads copies of your email, so you can move and delete them in the app without affecting the original emails.

POP settings for Yahoo Mail

Incoming Mail (POP) Server

```
Server - pop.mail.yahoo.com
Port - 995
Requires SSL - Yes
```

Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server

```
Server - smtp.mail.yahoo.com
Port - 465 or 587
Requires SSL - Yes
Requires TLS - Yes (if available)
Requires authentication - Yes
```

Your login info

```
Email address - Your full email address (name@domain.com.)
Password - Your account's password.
Requires authentication - Yes
```

Source: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/pop-access-settings-instructions-yahoo-mail-sln4724.html

Comment: I tried those settings. I get "Thunderbird failed to find settings for your email account."

Comment: Delete the Yahoo mail settings from Thunderbird and start over, trying IMAP first. Try letting Thunderbird configure itself automatically, after you've entered your email address.When done, you can compare the auto settings to my answer. I've also added settings for POP. See the two troubleshooting links at the top of my answer.

Comment: I did so. I also checked the trouble shooting links. Maybe an exorcism is needed? :-) What's frustrating is that it used to work.

Comment: sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      841/rpcbind         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      844/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      853/cupsd           
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      841/rpcbind         
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      853/cupsd

Comment: @fixit7 Are you able to log into their web/webmail GUI interface? You tried both IMAP and POP? You got an application-specific password, if required? You DELETED the existing yahoo mail settings and started over (vs editing what you had there before). There's so much information in my answer, there's got to be a solution... unless you've got more than just mail problems on your computer.

Comment: Yes, I can get message find thru Firefox. I have tried everything. I only have problems with Thunderbird. I installed Claws. Maybe I will luck out with it. :-)

Comment: @fixit7 in the image you showed, the incoming server AND port were wrong for IMAP. You didn't answer/respond to my last questions in my last comment.

Comment: I did respond to your last comment. Yes, I can get messages  thru Firefox. I have tried everything you have suggested. Is there a way to tell what ports are open? I use Verizon as my internet provider. I am trying to open the management console to see my firewall setting but not having any luck.

Comment: @fixit7 then I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to problem

I did a factory reset of the router(Netgear D2200D)

```
Reset Netgear D2200D router to factory defaults

To reset the Netgear D2200D to its default settings, you have to do the following steps:

    Turn on router
    Press Factory Reset button and hold for at least 15 seconds
    Device restarts automatically
    Default settings have been restored

 by pressing a recessed button in the back of the router for 20 seconds.
```