# Reminder program

Tags: firefox, crash, ubuntu-mate

Since Firefox made the Reminder Fox addon non-functional, I need a reminder program.

I tried DayPlanner but it often crashes.

Looking for recommendations for programs that work with Ubuntu Mate which has the Mate desktop. Thanks

Comment: You can use Thunderbird: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/creating-a-new-event-or-task

Comment: @pomsky The problem with that is I can not create an email account. Info is here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120732/thunderbird-can-not-get-messages/1120887?noredirect=1#comment1853113_1120887 I can not access TBs file menu.

Comment: Did you try GNOME Evolution (see [task management](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/index.html.en#memos-and-tasks))?

Comment: @ NOrbert I installed evolution. When I try an authentication request, it fails. It may be same problem I had with Thunderbird.